# How do you reload .vimperatorrc?

Tags: vimperator

I'm relatively new to Vimperator and have started adding preferences to my .vimperatorrc file. Is there a way of reloading this file without having to restart Firefox?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can load additions to your `~/.vimperatorrc` with

```
:source ~/.vimperatorrc
```

Note if you removed some setting from your configuration file, after sourcing the new file the old option settings will still be in place if they are not overwritten with some new setting, since basically `:source` just runs the configuration file as if you would enter them at the prompt.

Comment: Also, `autocommand` statements add up, but you can remove all of them using `au!` before reloading your .vimperratorrc.

Comment: sourcing the file like this seems to only affect the current window, at least for key mappings.